# ¿Cómo crear un objeto javascript para que C# lo convierta a DateTime?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero mandar una fecha desde javascript y debe ser leída como un dateTime en C#.

He creado un objeto en javascript y un post.

```js
var DateTime = (function () {
            function DateTime(anio, mes, dia) {
                if (dia != null && mes != null && anio != null) {
                    this.Day = dia;
                    this.Month = mes;
                    this.Year = anio;
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Fecha no valida");
                }
            }
return DateTime;
}());
var a = new DateTime(2003,2,1)

$('#altaPromo').click(function () {
            $.post({
                url: '/Promociones/AltaPromocion',
                data: {
                    promo: a,
                },
                success: function (r) {
                    if (r.Result == true)
                        alert("OK");
                    else
                        alert("KO");                        
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Error Post AltaPromocion");
                }
            })                      
     
    });
```

En C# lo recogería tal que así:

```js
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AltaPromocion(DateTime a)
        {
              return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Result = true } };     
      }
```

El objeto no se envía por un error en JS:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

¿Cómo puedo crear el objeto en JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu código encontré algo que posiblemente te resuelva el error 500. Resulta que muchas veces este error se  da por no mandar lls parametros de forma correcta, en este caso cuando mandas el post en tu data la variable la llamas promo y le asignas el valor de a (la fecha), pero en el método de c# al parámetro lo llamas a, con lo cual no se encuentra ningún parametro para esa función, lo que debes hacer es cambiar la palabra promo por a, de esta manera quedaría tu javascript:

```
var DateTime = (function () {
            function DateTime(anio, mes, dia) {
                if (dia != null && mes != null && anio != null) {
                    this.Day = dia;
                    this.Month = mes;
                    this.Year = anio;
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error("Fecha no valida");
                }
            }
return DateTime;
}());
var a = new DateTime(2003,2,1)

$('#altaPromo').click(function () {
            $.post({
                url: '/Promociones/AltaPromocion',
                data: {
                    a: a,
                },
                success: function (r) {
                    if (r.Result == true)
                        alert("OK");
                    else
                        alert("KO");                        
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Error Post AltaPromocion");
                }
            })                      

    });
```

De esta forma el dato debería llegar COMO UN STRING, por lo que recomiendo que el tipo de parametro en c# lo pongas como string y ya dentro de la función lo castees a DateTime.

de esta manera quedaría tu c#:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AltaPromocion(string a)
        {
                    return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Result = true }    };                    
            }
```

Ya edite la respuesta

Comment: yes, para mi la manera mas eficiente de mandar parametros desde ajax al lado del servidor es con strings y luego castearlos.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, el código es mucho mas complejo que todo esto. Por lo que solo he puesto un ejemplo con nombre de variables no reales y al subirlo a stackoverflow he olvidado cambiar el nombre del parametro de C#.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente envía la fecha en el formato ISO usando `.toISOString()` de los `Date` nativos de JavaScript . La fecha y hora en este formato no es suceptible de problemas de cultura por lo que el modelbinding debería funcionar sin problemas.

Ejemplo

```js
var fecha = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(fecha);
```

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado tu objeto `DateTime` y lo he convertido en una simple funcion llamada `getDateTime` que devuelve la hora en formato `DateTime` para C#, esta utilizar **`toJSON()`**, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp) is the documentation.

```js
function getDateTime(anio, mes , dia) {
 let date = new Date(anio, mes - 1, dia, 0,0,0,0);

 if (dia != null && mes != null && anio != null) {
  date.Day = dia;
  date.Month = mes;
  date.Year = anio;
 } else {
  throw new Error('Fecha no valida');
 }
 return date.toJSON();
}

var a = getDateTime(2003, 2, 1);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Este código lo puedes ejecutar en la consola y comprobarás que a es igual a la fecha actual, por lo que hay algún fallo. No obstante, gracias.

Comment: Perdon! No me di cuenta de ese error, ya esta arreglado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de una forma mucho más sencillo que todo eso. Simplemente :

```js
var a = new Date(2003, 2-1, 1);
a = a.toJSON();
```